# Deleting Youtube video in Google App Script

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, youtube, gmail

I have a bunch of Google accounts each with Youtube videos. What I want to achieve is a Google App Script which can read user credentials info from a google spreadsheet, get him login using his credentials, access the youtube video url which we have and delete it. 
Is this possible? i.e. Getting login into Gmail using Google App Script. If so then please provide a reference. 
Thanks.

Comment: I would love to see any reference that I could utilize as my starting point. Do you have any example to share

Answer (score 0):

```
YouTube.Videos.remove('Your_Video_Id_Here');
```

Did you look at the [reference material](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/delete)?

You can get the email of the active user with:

```
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

but you shouldn't need that if the person calls the function themselves via a menu/trigger/etc

Comment: I need to cover the scenario when the Admin is running the Google App script and He has to user other gmail accounts to get login and deleted video via Google App Script ?

Comment: Are the Google accounts yours or someone else's? Your question/comment doesn't make it very clear. If they aren't your accounts, you'll need to get the person to grant OAuth permissions and then access the YouTube API via UrlFetch or the OAuth2 library: https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2

Comment: I have like 20 accounts and I will act like an Admin deleting videos of these 20 accounts.

Comment: from the link  github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2. I am getting exception in the mthod authCallback(request) . Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined. the request parameter is undefined